# How to fetch the result of value in multidimensional associative array selected from dropdown in PHP form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, drop-down-menu, associative-array

The below is a multidimensional associative array.

```
   <?php

$schoolDetails = array(
    //First School Details
    array(

        array("schoolName" => "TCS"),


        array(
            "branchName"       => "Iqbal Campus",
            "phone"            => "052-4667281",
            "numberofTeachers" => 51
        ),

        array(
            "departmentNameOne" => "Maths",
            "HODOne"            => "Mr Ali",
            "departmentNameTwo" => "Science",
            "HODTwo"            => "Mr Imran"
        ),
    ),
    array(

        array("schoolName" => "CSS"),
        array(
            "branchName"       => "Gohdpur Campus",
            "phone"            => "052-4667281",
            "numberofTeachers" => 20
        ),
        array(
            "departmentNameOne" => "Chemistry",
            "HODOne"            => "Mr Abdullah",
            "departmentNameTwo" => "Computer",
            "HODTwo"            => "Mr Naeem"
        ),
        // array(
        //  "departmentName" => "Computer",
        //  "HOD"            => "Mr Naeem"
        // )
            
    ),
    array(

        array("schoolName" => "APS"),


        array(
            "branchName"       => "Cantt Campus",
            "phone"            => "052-4117281",
            "numberofTeachers" => 55
        ),

        array(
            "departmentNameOne" => "Maths",
            "HODOne"            => "Mr Imran",
            "departmentNameTwo" => "English",
            "HODTwo"            => "Mr Sami"
        ),
    ),
    array(

        array("schoolName" => "BCS"),
        array(
            "branchName"       => "Saidpur Campus",
            "phone"            => "052-4656211",
            "numberofTeachers" => 20
        ),
        array(
            "departmentNameOne" => "Physics",
            "HODOne"            => "Mr Kareem",
            "departmentNameTwo" => "Biology",
            "HODTwo"            => "Mr Inam"
        ),
        // array(
        //  "departmentName" => "Computer",
        //  "HOD"            => "Mr Naeem"
        // )
            
    ),

);
?>
```

I made a following dropdown form:

```
<form class="col-md-3" method="post">
        <select class="form-control" name="department_name">
            <option selected="selected" multiple>Select a Department</option>
            <option value="maths">Maths</option>
            <option value="physics">Physics</option>
            <option value="english">English</option>
            <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
            <option value="computer">Computer</option>
            <option value="biology">Biology</option>
            

            
        </select><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="department" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

The code for checking the department and fetching the results is:

```
    if (isset($_POST['department'])) {
        if ($_POST['department_name'] == 'maths') {
    
            for ($outerMost = 0; $outerMost < 1; $outerMost++) {
    
                for ($rowNum = 0; $rowNum < 3; $rowNum++) {
    
                    foreach ($schoolDetails[$outerMost][$rowNum] as $key => $value) {
    
                        echo "<td>$value</td>";
                        
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
        }
    

    }
```

But whenever I select the value from dropdown all the array's values appears. And I do not know how to display just a specific searched value's result. Therefore I want a guidance on whether I am doing the so thing correctly and how to fetch the value of only selected option from dropdown

Comment: if (isset($_POST['department_name'])) instead of if (isset($_POST['department']))

Comment: You array seems a very odd mix of positional and associative keys. Does it have to be like that because you could make it **a lot** simpler to work with?

Comment: exactly I just want to make it as simple as I can

Comment: It's not clear from your code what the result should be. Could you please give some examples?

Comment: @Jerson OP's submit button is named `"department"` so that part of the code is fine

Comment: so you mean that you want retrieve all values by department name? don't make it hardcoded. there is array_search

Comment: Could you please reduce the size of the manu-items array in yoru example so that it is simpler to read and find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's address your array. Make it easy to address and find data with something more like this

```php
$schoolDetails = [
    [
        "schoolName"       => "TCS",
        "branchName"       => "Iqbal Campus",
        "phone"            => "052-4667281",
        "numberofTeachers" => 51,
        "departments"      => [
            [
                "name" => "Maths",
                "HOD"  => "Mr Ali"
            ],
            [
                "name" => "Science",
                "HOD"  => "Mr Imran"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "schoolName"       => "CSS",
        // etc 
    ]
];
```

Now, assuming your form is some kind of search form where you want to search by department, you can use PHP's [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) to return all the school details matching the selected value

```php
if (!empty($_POST["department_name"])) {
    $searchResults = array_filter($schoolDetails, function($school) {
        $departmentNames = array_map(function($dep) {
            return $dep["name"];
        }, $school["departments"]);

        return in_array($_POST["department_name"], $departmentNames);
    });

    foreach ($searchResults as $school) {
        // just an example output
        echo "School: ", $school["name"], "<br>";
        echo "Branch: ", $school["branchName"];
        // etc
    }
}
```